Next js Link tag is not working as expected
I'm using Next.js version 14.1.0 in my current project. The problem I'm facing is that my link tag is not scrolling to the top of the page. I had never faced this problem some.
Code is given below
<Link
  href={`/companies/${company.ISIN}`}
  className="border relative hover:shadow rounded-xl w-full hover:bg-accent duration-300 "
  key={company.ISIN}
>
  <div className="absolute right-0 py-1 pr-2">
    <RenderBadge />
  </div>
  <div className="p-4">
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center mb-3">
      <Image
        width={250}
        height={250}
        alt="new"
        className="bg-white rounded-md"
        src={company.logo}
        loading="lazy"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="detail">
      <h2 className="text-xl font-bold capitalize">
        {company.name.toLocaleLowerCase()}
      </h2>
      <div className="mt-2">
        <p className="text-muted-foreground  text-xs">Sector</p>
        <h6 className="font-bold  text-muted-foreground text-xs">
          {company.sector}
        </h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Link>

